# Modify all the request made to the hapi server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, hapi.js

I have just started exploring Hapi server. I want to modify all the request made to the Hapi server before saving it to the back end. I came across 'server.ext' and tried writing the below code:

```
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {
    var path = request.path;
    path = path.replace(/\str1/g, 'str2')
    request.path = path;
    return reply.continue();
});
```

I want to update the request.path but this line of code is failing:

```
request.path = path;
```

What is the right way to do this? Is there any better way to modify all the requests to Hapi server?

Comment: Are you getting an error when it fails? What does it do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I've run some tests and I couldn't change request.path property in "onRequest" event, but managed to change in "onPreHandler".

"onRequest" always fires timeout error, means when you try to mutate request.path in "onRequest" event, you broke something internally I guess.

Here sample test code.

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Lab = require('lab');
const lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
const describe = lab.describe;
const it = lab.it;
const beforeEach = lab.beforeEach;
const expect = require('code').expect;

const plugin = (server, options, next) => {
    server.ext('onPreHandler', function (request, reply) {
        // let path = request.path;
        // // path = path.replace(/\str1/g, 'str2');
        request.path = 'xox';
        return reply.continue();
    });

    next();
};

plugin.attributes = {
    name: 'onRequest_test'
};

describe('Hapi server', () => {
    let server;
    beforeEach((done) => {
        server = new Hapi.Server();
        done();
    });


    it('should modify the path attribute', (done) => {
        server.connection();
        server.register({
            register: plugin
        }, (err) => {

            expect(err).to.not.exist();
            server.route({
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/',
                handler: (request, reply) => {
                    expect(request.path).to.equal('xox');

                    done();
                }
            });

            // call main route
            server.inject({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/'
            }, () => {
                //
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onRequest` event, and the request object has a method to update the path called [`setUrl`](https://hapijs.com/api#requestseturlurl-striptrailingslash).  You should use that, instead of altering the path directly

```
server.ext({
  type: 'onRequest',
  method: function (request, reply) {

    // Change all requests to '/test'
    request.setUrl('/test');
    return reply.continue();
  }
});
```